# How to use MVVM Light Messenger in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone

I am trying to learn how to use the messenger class in MVVM Light but nothing ever get sent.

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly INavigationService navigationService = null;
        public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
            SecondPgCmd = new RelayCommand(() => SecondPg());

        }

        private void SecondPg()
        {

            Messenger.Default.Send<string>("my message");
            navigationService.NavigateTo("/Views/SecondPg.xaml");
        }


        public RelayCommand SecondPgCmd
        {
            get;
            private set;
        } 

    }


    public class SecondVm : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the SecondVm class.
        /// </summary>
        public SecondVm()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, x => MyProperty = x);
        }

           /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="MyProperty" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";

        private string myProperty = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets and gets the MyProperty property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return myProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                if (myProperty == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                RaisePropertyChanging(() => MyProperty);
                myProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyProperty);
            }
        }
    }

  static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SecondVm>();
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you created `SecondVm` before sending the message?

Comment: I think so as I have the ViewModelLocator.

Comment: Hmm ya was thinking about it. I guess it actually is not created unless I would pass in "true".  I am not sure how to send data between views then. I thought messenger was the way to go but I must be missing a step.

Comment: You are not supposed to share data this way anyway. Messaging is used for passing data between two *active* views. If you need to retain some data for future access, then create a repository and access it via `SimpleIoc`.

Comment: What do you mean create a repository? Say if I have a list of choices, They click on Choice 1, it goes to another screen in which you want to download data from the server. You need to send the ID of Choice 1. You need to get that to the new view somehow. Also I don't see when you would really use messaging in Windows Phone app then.

Comment: @ToniPetrina - Could you please elaborate on what you mean with the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messaging is used to pass parameters from one service to another. In this case when you want to save data for later use, it would be best to keep it somewhere. The proposed solution by @sibbl might work, but you are needlessly creating a view model that is not used (yet) and the solution doesn't scale.

Since you already have `SimpleIoc` at hand, simply create a new object and put it inside. Lke this:

```
class ImportantMessageService
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}


// in locator
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ImportantMessageService>();


// in page 1
var service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ImportantMessageService>();
service.Message = "Hello world";


// in page 2
var service = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ImportantMessageService>();
MessageBox.Show(service.Message);
```

This way all participants in the communication use central service where they keep data. This scales well because in case you never go to the second page, the data is simply unused. The only thing you need to worry about here is tombstoning.

Comment: Hmm, You service more just seems like a model. I am not sure when you would use by "Messaging is used to pass parameters from one service to another" as in your example you don't use the Messenger at all. What would happen when tombstoned? I thought everything is killed and recreated when the app comes back? Also how big of an issue is that now with fast switching?

Comment: It doesn't matter how it looks but what it does. Tombstoning depends on your application, I merely mentioned it as a potential problem, and not as certain one. What I said about messaging does not apply to *my* code but rather to general principle. For example, when you want to navigate away, you issue a message "please navigate". When you want to save data for later use, you *store* it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `true` as the first Parameter when registering your view models, which register for messages. This way, they will be created immediately and register for messages right from the beginning, not when the views are called.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SecondVm>(true);
```

See [this great article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/simpleioc-and-messenger) to learn more about messaging, where this problem is also being discussed.

Comment: Ya that was the problem.

Comment: I would appreciate you to mark it as the answer then ;) Thanks.